# Log into GMail without SSL

Tags: ssl, internet, webfilter

Since the 443 ports for HTTPS is filtered  in Iran, is there any alternative method of logging into GMail which does not require the use of this port?

Comment: we cant reach Gmail login page and proxy doesn't work

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on superuser.com

Comment: Duplicate question? http://superuser.com/questions/43571/log-into-gmail-without-ssl

Comment: This is more than a duplicate. It's an exact exact copy from the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the "Browser Connection" option in your Gmail settings to "Don't always use https", then it should not force you to the https connection if you just use "http://"

Comment: It's nice that SjB accepted an answer to indicate the problem has been solved, but just for the archives: like noted on Super User, this option does *not* stop Google from requiring HTTPS during log in. Many more details on Super User at http://superuser.com/questions/43571

Answer (score 0):

You can hit it via an IMAP client and use IMAPS (IMAP over SSL). Or is IMAPS blocked as well?

Comment: NO i can't use smtp or imap